# Syntax error on complex MySQL sub-queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I can not see the problem here, unless I simply don't understand sub-queries in MySQL. I was given a slow query that had a lot of LEFT JOINs, so I was trying to re-write those JOINs as sub-queries. I started like this:

```
  select t.title AS title,
  (select 
    group_concat(distinct haha_supplier.display_name order by haha_supplier.display_name ASC separator ', ') AS contributors
    from haha_supplier where haha_supplier.supplier_id IN
               (select haha_title_to_supplier.supplier_id from haha_title_to_supplier where haha_title_to_supplier.title_id = t.title_id))
                  AS contributors,
  (select haha_supplier.supplier_id
    from haha_supplier where 
    where haha_supplier.supplier_id IN
               (select haha_title_to_supplier.supplier_id from haha_title_to_supplier where haha_title_to_supplier.title_id = t.title_id))
                 AS supplier_id,
  (select haha_supplier.group_letter
    from haha_supplier where 
    where haha_supplier.supplier_id IN
               (select haha_title_to_supplier.supplier_id from haha_title_to_supplier where haha_title_to_supplier.title_id = t.title_id))
                 AS group_letter,
  select 
         group_concat(distinct concat(user.first_name,' ',user.last_name) separator ', ') as marketer
         from user where user.id IN
                (select wawa_suppliers_to_haha_marketing_contacts.user_id from wawa_suppliers_to_haha_marketing_contacts
                where wawa_suppliers_to_haha_marketing_contacts.supplier_id IN
                  (select haha_supplier.supplier_id
                   where haha_supplier.supplier_id IN
                     (select haha_title_to_supplier.supplier_id from haha_title_to_supplier where haha_title_to_supplier.title_id = t.title_id)))
                         AS marketer,
  select 
         group_concat(distinct concat(user.first_name,' ',user.last_name) separator ', ') AS editor
         from user where user.id IN
                (select wawa_suppliers_to_haha_editors.user_id from wawa_suppliers_to_haha_editors
                where wawa_suppliers_to_haha_editors.supplier_id IN
                  (select haha_supplier.supplier_id
                   where haha_supplier.supplier_id IN
                     (select haha_title_to_supplier.supplier_id from haha_title_to_supplier where haha_title_to_supplier.title_id = t.title_id)))
                         AS editor,
```

I got:

```
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '       from haha_supplier where haha_supplier.supplier_id IN
                 (select haha_title_to_supplier.supplier_id from haha_title_to_supplier where haha_title_to_supplier.title_id = t.title_id))'
```

What is the syntax error here?

Comment: You have `where \n where` in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>select t.title AS title,
    (select 
      group_concat(distinct haha_supplier.display_name order by haha_supplier.display_name ASC separator ', ') AS contributors
      from haha_supplier where haha_supplier.supplier_id IN
                                                        ^----</strike>

You're missing `where somefield` at the indicated spot...

monday blindness... leaving this up as a personal hairshirt.

Comment: d'oh... my bad. mondays, sorry. there is a where there. I'm just blind. however, you do have too many `where` everywhere else in the query.

Comment: Thanks for that. The error message seems to be misleading. It points to the wrong line.

Comment: the error messages are approximations... the first place where an error was actually detected. with some syntax errors, the error can be anywhere BEFORE that spot, and the indicated spot is merely the first place where the bad syntax actually confused the parser.